# Add values to a graph depending of a value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently working on a project which needs to build graph regarding to a table of analyses to check if the products work with time.

The user starts to choose which products he want to check and the code create a table regarding that.

The two main values are the date and the result which need to be on the graph and the third one is the batch number which needs to be the name of each chart series.

[image: An example of a part of the table that the code create]

After that the code creates a 2D array with the table.

```
For Each elementReo In Range("tabReorganize[Date]")
   ReDim Preserve tabReo(2, r)
   tabReo(0, r) = elementReo
   tabReo(1, r) = 0 & elementReo.Offset(0, 1)
   tabReo(2, r) = elementReo.Offset(0, 2)
   r = r + 1
Next elementReo
```

And after that I want to create the graph regarding to the number of different batch number that I have.

```
'This part create the Chart and set the title
    Set ChartObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=2979.75, Width:=550, Top:=358.5, Height:=325)
    ChartObj.Chart.ChartType = xlLine
    ChartObj.Chart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
    ChartObj.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Humidite"
    
    Dim tabNBN() As String
    Dim NBN As Integer
    Dim checkNBN As Boolean
    ReDim tabNBN(NBN)
    Dim SeriesI As Integer
    
    NBN = 0
    SeriesI = 0
    
    'Add value in tabNBN regarding to the number of different batch number
    For r2 = 0 To r - 1 Step 1
        checkNBN = False
        For Each elementNBN In tabNBN
            If elementNBN = tabReo(1, r2) Then
                checkNBN = True
            End If
        Next elementNBN
                    
        If checkNBN = False Then
            ReDim Preserve tabNBN(NBN)
            tabNBN(NBN) = tabReo(1, r2)
            NBN = NBN + 1
        End If
    Next r2
```

So I need something to add the series regarding of the number of different batch number and insert the value and the date there.

I'm a beginner with charts in VBA.

Comment: I am sorry I could not understand what exactly you want to do. Is it possible to show an example of how the graph needs to look?

Comment: That's a example of which type of chart i need without valeus https://imgur.com/a/ZlWAEZa

Comment: So you want something that will plot the humidtie vs date for each batch number on the same chart?

Comment: Yes but the number of bacth number can change, in the example above i need 4 lines with humidite regarding to dates for each batch number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if my understanding of the objective is correct then congratulation for a good & challenging question. Assuming the objective is to create a single chart with  multiple series representing each batch listed in the range. If assumed result is like the following

[image]

then may try the test code (obviously after modifying the range, sheet etc to requirement). The code used Dictionary object, so please add Tools-> Reference  to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime". Though I am not fully satisfied with the code regarding some multiple looping etc (degrading the performance) but would work OK with normal data assuming 100/200 rows. I invite experts response for more efficient code in this regard

```
Option Explicit
Sub test3()
    Dim Cht As Chart, ChartObj As ChartObject
    Set ChartObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=10, Width:=550, Top:=10, Height:=325)
    'Set ChartObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 4")
    Set Cht = ChartObj.Chart
    Cht.ChartType = xlLine
    Cht.HasTitle = True
    Cht.ChartTitle.Text = "Humidite"


    Dim Rw As Long, Dic As Dictionary, DataArr As Variant, OutArr() As Variant, BatchArr() As Variant, DateArr As Variant
    Dim Rng As Range, SeriesNo As Long, Dmax As Date, Dmin As Date, dt As Date
    Dim X As Long, i As Long, Xbatch As Variant, Batch As Variant
    Dim Cnt As Long, Xval As Variant, PrvDt As Date, C As Range, DayCnt As Long
    Dim firstAddress As String

    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")
    Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A100")  'Modify to requireMent
    DataArr = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A2:C100")  'Modify to requireMent
    SeriesNo = 0

        'Create dictionary reference to unique Batch name from the list
        For Rw = 1 To UBound(DataArr, 1)
        Batch = DataArr(Rw, 2)
            If Dic.Exists(Batch) = False Then
            SeriesNo = SeriesNo + 1
            Dic.Add Batch, SeriesNo
            End If
        Next

Dmax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(Rng(1, 1), Rng(Rng.Rows.Count, 1)))
Dmin = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range(Rng(1, 1), Rng(Rng.Rows.Count, 1)))
DayCnt = Dmax - Dmin + 1

ReDim BatchArr(1 To DayCnt)
ReDim DateArr(1 To DayCnt)
ReDim OutArr(1 To SeriesNo, 1 To DayCnt)

    'Populate DateArr for dates
    For X = 1 To DayCnt
    DateArr(X) = Dmin + X - 1
    Next

    'Populate OutArr(Series,DayCnt) with existing Values, Non existing values are kept empty
    For X = 1 To DayCnt
    dt = DateArr(X)
    With Rng
    Set C = .Find(dt)
        If Not C Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = C.Address
            Do
            OutArr(Dic(C.Offset(0, 1).Value), X) = C.Offset(0, 2).Value
            'Debug.Print C.Value, C.Offset(0, 1).Value, C.Offset(0, 2).Value
            Set C = .FindNext(C)
            Loop While Not C Is Nothing And C.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    End With
    Next

With Cht
    'delete If any automatically added series
    For i = Cht.SeriesCollection.Count To 1 Step -1
    .SeriesCollection(i).Delete
    Next


    'Create Series and Set Values & Xvalues from OutArr
    Dim Srs As Series
    For X = 1 To SeriesNo
    Batch = Dic.Keys(X - 1)
        For Cnt = 1 To DayCnt
        BatchArr(Cnt) = OutArr(Dic(Batch), Cnt)
        'If IsEmpty(BatchArr(Cnt)) = False Then Debug.Print X, Cnt, BatchArr(Cnt), DateArr(Cnt)
        Next
    Cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    Set Srs = Cht.SeriesCollection(X)
        With Srs
        .Values = BatchArr
        .XValues = DateArr
        .Name = Dic.Keys(X - 1)
        End With
    Next

    Dim Cat As Axis
    Set Cat = Cht.Axes(xlCategory)
    Cat.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy"

End With
End Sub
```

Please comment if it suits your need

Comment: I tried your code but the chart doesn't display the values. I will post the code and the file where i'm trying to do that below this comment.

Answer (score 0):

This code should create a table regarding to another table (the one with all different batch numbers and values) and the user selection and after build the chart with it.

I can send you the full file by mail if needed.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards

colin

```
Private Sub BtnGraph2_Click()
    Dim tabBNumber() As String
    Dim tabHumidite() As Double
    Dim tabDate() As String
    Dim tabReo() As String
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim h As Integer
    Dim d As Integer
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim w As Integer
    Dim w2 As Integer
    Dim r As Integer
    h = 0
    y = 0
    d = 0
    w = 1
    w2 = 1
    r = 0
    ReDim tabHumidite(h)
    ReDim tabBNumber(y)
    ReDim tabDate(d)
    Range("tabReorganize[#data]") = ""
    ListObjects("tabReorganize").Resize Range(Range("tabReorganize[#headers]").Address, Range("tabReorganize[#headers]").Offset(1).Address)


    For i6 = ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If ListBox1.Selected(i6) = True Then
            ReDim Preserve tabBNumber(y)
            tabBNumber(y) = ListBox1.List(i6)
            y = y + 1
        End If
    Next i6

    For Each delement In tabBNumber
        For Each delement2 In Range("tabGraph[Date]")
            If "0" & delement2.Offset(0, 2) = delement Or delement2.Offset(0, 2) = delement Then
                ReDim Preserve tabDate(d)
                tabDate(d) = delement2
                d = d + 1
            End If
        Next delement2
    Next delement

    For Each Oelement In tabDate
        Range("tabReorganize[Date]").Cells(w) = Format(Oelement, "mm/dd/yyyy")
        w = w + 1
    Next Oelement



    If BtnHumidite = True Then
        For Each element In tabBNumber
            h = 0
            a = 0
            ReDim tabHumidite(h)

            For Each Gelement In Range("tabGraph[Humidite]")
                If "0" & Gelement.Offset(0, -1) = element Or Gelement.Offset(0, -1) = element Then
                    ReDim Preserve tabHumidite(h)
                    tabHumidite(h) = Gelement
                    h = h + 1
                End If
            Next Gelement


            For Each O2element In tabHumidite
                Range("tabReorganize[Humidite]").Cells(w2) = Format(O2element, "###0.00")
                Range("tabReorganize[Batch Number]").Cells(w2) = Format(element, "00000000")
                w2 = w2 + 1
            Next O2element
        Next element
    End If

    Range("tabReorganize").Sort Key1:=Range("tabReorganize[[#All],[Date]]"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

    For Each elementReo In Range("tabReorganize[Date]")
        ReDim Preserve tabReo(2, r)
        tabReo(0, r) = elementReo
        tabReo(1, r) = 0 & elementReo.Offset(0, 1)
        tabReo(2, r) = elementReo.Offset(0, 2)
        r = r + 1
    Next elementReo

    '''' Chart part

    Dim Cht As Chart, ChartObj As ChartObject
    Set ChartObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=2979.75, Width:=550, Top:=358.5, Height:=325)
    Set Cht = ChartObj.Chart
    Cht.ChartType = xlLine
    Cht.HasTitle = True
    Cht.ChartTitle.Text = "Humidite"


    Dim Rw As Long, Dic As Dictionary, DataArr As Variant, OutArr() As Variant, BatchArr() As Variant, DateArr As Variant
    Dim Rng As Range, SeriesNo As Long, Dmax As Date, Dmin As Date, dt As Date
    Dim X As Long, i As Long, Xbatch As Variant, Batch As Variant
    Dim Cnt As Long, Xval As Variant, PrvDt As Date, C As Range, DayCnt As Long
    Dim firstAddress As String

    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")
    Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("AP13:AP42")  'Modify to requireMent
    'Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("tabReorganize[Date]")
    DataArr = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("AP13:AR42")  'Modify to requireMent
    'DataArr = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("tabReorganize[#data]")
    SeriesNo = 0

        'Create dictionary reference to unique Batch name from the list
        For Rw = 1 To UBound(DataArr, 1)
        Batch = DataArr(Rw, 2)
            If Dic.Exists(Batch) = False Then
            SeriesNo = SeriesNo + 1
            Dic.Add Batch, SeriesNo
            End If
        Next

Dmax = Application.WorksheetFunction.max(Range(Rng(1, 1), Rng(Rng.Rows.Count, 1)))
Dmin = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range(Rng(1, 1), Rng(Rng.Rows.Count, 1)))
DayCnt = Dmax - Dmin + 1

ReDim BatchArr(1 To DayCnt)
ReDim DateArr(1 To DayCnt)
ReDim OutArr(1 To SeriesNo, 1 To DayCnt)

    'Populate DateArr for dates
    For X = 1 To DayCnt
    DateArr(X) = Dmin + X - 1
    Next

    'Populate OutArr(Series,DayCnt) with existing Values, Non existing values are kept empty
    For X = 1 To DayCnt
    dt = DateArr(X)
    With Rng
    Set C = .Find(dt)
        If Not C Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = C.Address
            Do
            OutArr(Dic(C.Offset(0, 1).Value), X) = C.Offset(0, 2).Value
            'Debug.Print C.Value, C.Offset(0, 1).Value, C.Offset(0, 2).Value
            Set C = .FindNext(C)
            Loop While Not C Is Nothing And C.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    End With
    Next

With Cht
    'delete If any automatically added series
    For i = Cht.SeriesCollection.Count To 1 Step -1
    .SeriesCollection(i).Delete
    Next


    'Create Series and Set Values & Xvalues from OutArr
    Dim Srs As Series
    For X = 1 To SeriesNo
    Batch = Dic.Keys(X - 1)
        For Cnt = 1 To DayCnt
        BatchArr(Cnt) = OutArr(Dic(Batch), Cnt)
        'If IsEmpty(BatchArr(Cnt)) = False Then Debug.Print X, Cnt, BatchArr(Cnt), DateArr(Cnt)
        Next
    Cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    Set Srs = Cht.SeriesCollection(X)
        With Srs
        .Values = BatchArr
        .XValues = DateArr
        .Name = Dic.Keys(X - 1)
        End With
    Next

    Dim Cat As Axis
    Set Cat = Cht.Axes(xlCategory)
    Cat.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"

End With
```